# Elastic search advanced query for showing price changes on time series indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elasticsearch-painless

I have separated my time-series data into day wise indexes.
Let's say I have 2 days indexes.

1) index1 **data-timeseries-14-04-2019** :

example data:

```
{{"_id": 1,
  "product_name": "mobile1",
  "product_id": "12145",
  "created_at": "2014-04-14",
  "offer_price": 89
  },
 {"_id": 2,
  "product_name": "mobile2",
  "product_id": "12146",
  "created_at": "2014-04-14",
  "offer_price": 70
  }
 }
```

2) index2 **data-timeseries-15-04-2019** :

```
{{"_id": 1,
  "product_name": "mobile2",
  "product_id": "12146",
  "created_at": "2014-04-15",
  "offer_price": 80
  },
 {"_id": 2,
  "product_name": "mobile1",
  "product_id": "12145",
  "created_at": "2014-04-15",
  "offer_price": 89
  }
 }
`
```

**Here unique products are identified by their "product_id"**

I want to write a query showing **number of products, those have changed their offer_price.**

please help me out.

I tried something like this

```
{

    "aggs": {
        "distinct_by_product_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "product_id.keyword",
                "min_doc_count": 2,
                "size": 10

            },
            "aggs": {"count_distinct_prices":
                {"cardinality": {
                    "field": "offer_price"
                }}
            }
        }}

}
```

First applying term aggregation on product_id and then finding the distinct no offer_price. if the distinct no is larger than 1, that product is counted as price variant product.

- But as I am using term aggregation, for large no of data I can't get all products data.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the `size` parameter to change the number of distinct products returned, but this may cause performance problems.

Comment: I tried this. But this took a huge time. not useful